# design usercontrol properties grouping in class

Tags: c#

My objectives are easy :

[image]

On this first picture I would like to have the + (plus) button on the left of "AttrbMandUserInpFail" row.
I describe my class outside the usercontrol class ==> result KO
I describe my class inside the usercontrol class ==> result KO

set the property :

`[Category("_ExtendedAttributes"), Description("Attributs Etendus"), Browsable(true)]

public CLS_AttrbMandFailUserInput AttrbMandUserInpFail { get => _AttrbMandFailUserInput; set => _AttrbMandFailUserInput = value; }`

And my class is :

```
public class CLS_AttrbMandFailUserInput
{
    private Color _BackColor = Color.Coral;
    private string _TooltipText = "This cell is mandatory";
    private Image _Image = null;

    [Category("_ExtendedAttributes"), Description("Attributs Etendus")]
    public Color BackColor { get => _BackColor; set => _BackColor = value; }
    [Category("_ExtendedAttributes"), Description("Attributs Etendus")]
    public string TooltipText { get => _TooltipText; set => _TooltipText = value; }
    [Category("_ExtendedAttributes"), Description("Attributs Etendus")]
    public Image Image { get => _Image; set => _Image = value; }

    public CLS_AttrbMandFailUserInput() { }
    public CLS_AttrbMandFailUserInput(Color BackColor) { _BackColor = BackColor; }
    public CLS_AttrbMandFailUserInput(Color BackColor, string TooltipText)
    {
        _BackColor = BackColor;
        _TooltipText = TooltipText;
    }
    public CLS_AttrbMandFailUserInput(Color BackColor, string TooltipText, Image Image)
    {
        _BackColor = BackColor;
        _TooltipText = TooltipText;
        _Image = Image;
    }
}
```

I tried to overload procedures of instanciation but no effect

Where are errors ?

Comment: [Expandable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa302334(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#expandable-properties-and-string-conversion-typeconverters-and-the-property-browser). I'd read the other sections as well. See also [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert) article.

Comment: interesting but complex. I must study this seriously. thank you "dr.null"